# Jquery getScript issue with json calls

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, jsonp, getscript

Greetings, recently I had this code working. After loading **Jquery** I do:

```
function twitterCallback2(twitters) {
var statusHTML = [];
for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
  return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
}).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
  return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
});
statusHTML.push('<li><span>'+status+'</span> <a style="font-size:85%" href="http://twitter.com/'+username+'/statuses/'+twitters[i].id_str+'">'+relative_time(twitters[i].created_at)+'</a></li>');
}
  if(document.getElementById('twitter_update_list').length>0)
  document.getElementById('twitter_update_list').innerHTML = statusHTML.join('');
}

function relative_time(time_value) {
var values = time_value.split(" ");
time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

if (delta < 60) {
    return 'Hace menos de un minuto';
} else if(delta < 120) {
    return 'hace un minuto';
} else if(delta < (60*60)) {
    return "Hace "+(parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutos';
} else if(delta < (120*60)) {
    return 'Hace una hora';
} else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
    return 'Hace ' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' horas';
} else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
    return 'Hace un día';
} else {
    return "Hace "+ (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' días';
  }
}

$.getScript("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/buscocarro.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=10", function(){});
```

Until some days ago it stopped working and the **Google Chrome** *console* says:

> Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

Any of you could tell me what happened and how it can be solved?
thanks a lot

Comment: it doesn't work doing an Ajax call because javascript doesn't allow cross-domain calls

Comment: Well JavaScript does now allow cross-domain calls when both the browser and the remote site support [`CORS` (Cross-origin resource sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a standard AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/buscocarro.json?count=10',
    success: twitterCallback2
});
```

That would do the same thing, but wouldn't load the file as a script.

Comment: yeah, but you can't do cross-domain ajax request.